# Solve the equation for $t: U_c = U_0 (1-e^{(-t/T)})$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

How to solve the following equation:
$$U_c = U_0  (1-e^\frac{-t}{T})$$

The result should be this:

$$t = \ln(1-\frac{U_c}{U_0})^{-T}$$

What I did as far:

\begin{align}U_c = U_0 * (1-e^\frac{-t}{T}) &\implies \frac{U_c}{U_0} = (1-e^\frac{-t}{T}) &|: U_0\\
&\implies \frac{U_c}{U_0}-1 = -e^\frac{-t}{T} &|: -1\\
&\implies 1-\frac{U_c}{U_0} = e^\frac{-t}{T} &| \times(-1)\end{align}
and now I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking logarithm on both sides

$$\ln \left( 1- \frac{U_c}{U_0}\right)=-\frac{t}{T}$$

$$-T\ln \left( 1- \frac{U_c}{U_0}\right)=t$$

Since $a\ln b = \ln b^a$, we have

$$t=\ln \left( 1- \frac{U_c}{U_0}\right)^{-T}$$

Comment: so basically when i do ln on both side e(Euler) is removed.
If i it was a instead of e, I would need to do $log_a$ ?

Comment: yes, you get it right.